# Find process started by Autostart (Redshift)

Tags: process, grep, autostart

I've tried `pgrep redshift, pgrep -f redshift,  ps -ax | grep redshift,  ps -elf | grep redshift,  ps -ax -u root -U root | g redshift,  systemctl | grep redshift` all without finding the process, yet the icon is sitting in the System Tray and I can adjust the settings via the command line. It is listed in my Autostart GUI in Kubuntu as redshift-gtk.

I'm trying to set the temp to a specific level, because clicking the icon steps are to large of dimming, using this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1077895/795299, and then restart redshift.

Requested in comment:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/redshift-gtk
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/redshift_gtk
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/redshift_gtk/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/redshift_gtk/controller.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/redshift_gtk/defs.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/redshift_gtk/statusicon.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/redshift_gtk/utils.py
/usr/lib/systemd
/usr/lib/systemd/user
/usr/lib/systemd/user/redshift-gtk.service
/usr/share
/usr/share/appdata
/usr/share/appdata/redshift-gtk.appdata.xml
/usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/redshift-gtk.desktop
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/redshift-gtk
/usr/share/doc/redshift-gtk/copyright
/usr/share/icons
/usr/share/icons/hicolor
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/redshift-status-off.svg
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/redshift-status-on.svg
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/redshift.svg
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/scalable
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/scalable/apps
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/scalable/apps/redshift-status-off.svg
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/scalable/apps/redshift-status-on.svg
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/scalable
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/scalable/apps
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/scalable/apps/redshift-status-off.svg
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/scalable/apps/redshift-status-on.svg
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/menu
/usr/share/menu/redshift-gtk
/usr/bin/gtk-redshift
/usr/share/doc/redshift-gtk/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/redshift-gtk/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/redshift-gtk/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/redshift-gtk.1.gz

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                  Version                 Architecture            Description
+++-=====================================-=======================-=======================-================================================================================
ii  redshift                              1.12-2                  amd64                   Adjusts the color temperature of your screen
ii  redshift-gtk                          1.12-2                  all                     Adjusts the color temperature of your screen with GTK+ integration
un  redshift-plasmoid                     <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
```

Comment: Related: [Can't disable redshift](https://askubuntu.com/q/561373/968501)

Comment: @Raffa, thanks, saw that.. Whats strange is using ```redshift -O 6000``` makes the steps much smaller, solving my initial problem. I find it stranger though that the process is nowhere to be found. Other ones listed in Autostart and also found under /home/$USER/.config/autostart like Duplicati are found using pgrep -f

Comment: List all the files in the package: `dpkg -L redshift-gtk` and `dpkg -l 'redshift*'`

Comment: @waltinator, added. Does that help?